# How do I make the background of Highchart's SVG clock transparent?

Tags: svg, highcharts

I am trying to place the clock on top of an image but I can't figure out how to make the background of the SVG transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/YWUvU/

```
chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        height: 200
    },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/YWUvU/1/